# "just like " and "like"

Tags: grammar

I saw a photo this morning and there were two sisters in the photo. One of them says   "I am dressed just like my sister"...and I wonder,
if it was "I am dressed like my sister" instead, would there be any problem?

What is the difference between "just like" and "like"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just can be used as a modifier meaning "exactly". You use just in expressions such as just like, just as...as, and just the same when you are emphasizing the similarity between two things or two people.

"I am dressed like my sister" could mean that you are dressed exactly like your sister, or it could mean only that you are both wearing jeans, or a hat, or something.

"I am dressed just like my sister" means that everything that you are both wearing is exactly the same - that you look like copies of each other.

[Just like](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just)